# Best way to store buyers data in checkout

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, shopping-cart, checkout

I am stuck with my application right now. I want to make an simple e-commerce store within my application.

What I got it a view where the user can choose between multiple items which are then stored in a "cart". The cart is represented in another VC and it stores the items, quantity and total costs.

After the user continues the order he can fill in all the required infos about himself in a nice form which is presented after the cart.

My problem: I am looking for a good solution to store the entered date ad the data of the shipment somewhere in a backend where I can access a list of all orders made. What is the best/convenient way to accomplish this?

Additionally I want to use the Paypal API as a payment provider. Does it come with such a "store" feature?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, this question will likely be too broad and/or opinionated. You seem to already know what is needed - re: a "backend system" to handle "fulfillment operations". The quick answer is: you can "build or buy". For the former, you're going to have to try first and come back if you get stuck with some specific item. For the latter, perhaps, [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) will be more appropriate. Paypal handles payment transactions (only). There are several providers (aka "buy"). Hth~

Comment: @EdSF I thought of parse as a backend. I would like to know if there would be better solution. Maybe someone has some experience in building shops in applications.